# Power Automate can't find table in excel: No table was found with the name 'SNOW'

Tags: power-automate, excel-online

I am creating a Power Automate flow, which triggers when a file is dropped into a SharePoint folder.

It triggers fine - and I'm locating the file from the dropdowns in the "List Rows Present in a Table" action.

When it triggers, it errors and says:

> No table was found with the name 'SNOW'.

As below:

[image: Power Automate Error]

The table is named in the Excel file (Table Design tab):

[image: Excel Named Table]

Can you see anything wrong with what I've done? Have I named the table in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the tables on a file with the Get Tables action. I would suggest to use a Get Tables first before the list rows action. That might help troubleshooting the issue of not being able to find your SNOW table.

[image]

Btw, how did you enter the SNOW table name? Did you select it from the dropdown as well or did you enter it as a custom value?

[image]

Comment: Hi - I created another flow with just GetTables and it worked (in the return values I can see the SNOW table). The only difference is that this one was manually triggered, rather than being when a new file is dropped in the source directory.

So thank you for the prompt to check - it seems the problem with that flow is elsewhere (in how it's triggered, or possibly latency).

Cheers